# Is there a way to generate output from a List<List<Integer>> object?

Tags: java

I have the following code and would like to generate output. At this point, generating a functional output of 'obj' and 'obj2' would help tremendously.

Main file:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] nums = {1,2,3};
        Solution obj = new Solution();
        obj.permute(nums);

    }
}
```

Solution file:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums)
    {

        List<Integer> obj;
        obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        List<List<Integer>> obj2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();


        for(int i = 0 ; i < nums.length;i++)
        {

            obj.add(nums[i]);


        }

        return obj2.add(obj);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
java: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>>
```

Expected Output:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
```

Comment: Do you mean to `return obj2;` after mutating it?

Comment: Your compilation error is occurring because the value is `obj2.add(obj)` is `true` or `false`.  Read the javadocs! If you want to return `obj2`, use `return obj2;` not `return obj2.add(obj);`.

Answer (score 1):

The add method returns a boolean, as per the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)

Thus when you try to return obj2.add(obj) you are actually returning True, since that is what the add method returns. What you should do instead is as follows:

```
obj2.add(obj);
return obj2;
```

This won't give you the functionality that you are looking for, since all you've done is copy the input array into a list and put it into another list. If you are looking to return all permutations you will have to do some more work.